# When object variable is reassigned in Javascript, what happens to the original object?

Tags: javascript, class, variables, object, declaration

Let's say in the beginning we will:

```
class AI {
// class properties/methods here
}
var chappie = new AI;
```

Then after using the variable, if I want to reset it by calling:

```
chappie = new AI;
```

what happens to original object? Does it get garbage collected? Is this allowed, or there is a better way to "reset" a variable?

Comment: Unless there is another referance it is removed by GC. This is the accepted way of removing unwanted memory allocations. Call dereferencing.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "reset." You will create a new object and assign it to that variable. But if you just want to throw away the previous object, do set the variable to null and don't create a new one. Was a bit unclear what your intention was.

Comment: *"is there a better way"* ... probably not if all you want to do is overwrite the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no more references to an object, then the object will eventually be garbage-collected.

If you originally had 1 reference, and now you have none, eventually the memory will be freed.

```
var obj = { };
var a = obj;
var b = obj;
a = null;
```

There's still a reference, so nothing changes.

As to the other question: "How else would I reset a variable?"
My follow-up question is "Why?"

If you want the GC to kick in, then you can set the var to `null` or to `undefined` or whatever (assuming it's the last time the object is referenced).

...otherwise, the GC will also clean up the var, itself, when the var isn't needed by anything anymore.
And if the var that's been removed was the last reference to a value, then the value will be cleaned up.

Comment: vars will not be removed until they are out of scope. It is preferable to use `undefined` rather than `null` as undefined has a more meaningful contextual meaning than null. Also `null` is serialised to JSON and `undefined` is ignored.

Comment: @Blindman67: `null` has the meaning "no object", which is exactly what is preferred here.

Comment: @Bergi null is a placeholder. it means there is no applicable value for the variable at the moment, but that we wish to hold (reserve) this variable in case there is a future need. Undefined is literal in meaning and refers to non existing undefined entities. It is assigned to indicate that there is no further need for the variable and it no longer has meaningful context. A variable with the value null must be preserved during serialization/transfer/cloning, unlike a variable with undefined, which can be dumped. If you have no further use for a variable set it to undefined.

Comment: @Blindman67. I agree that undefined is more symantically correct than null, but in JS `undefined` represents **both** undeclared vars and `var test=undefined`. So a typical safety check (`typeof test==='undefined'`) will unfortunately return true both when `test` is undeclared and when `test` is assigned undefined. Assigning `test=null` first allows for a proper safety check (`typeof test==='undefined'`) and then allows for `if(test===null)`. And...(he says softly so no-one hears) ... null is only 4 characters to type while undefined is 9 characters to type. :-O

Comment: @markE Quote MDN "However, this kind of technique should be avoided. " referring to `typeof ? === "undefined"` and they are correct that there is no need for this test as you should know the scope of the variables and referance it as a property. `window["v"] === undefined` The widespread use of `null` instead of `undefined` means I have to vet arguments `arg !== undefined && !== null ? arg : defV` which is ugly and inefficient. For 5 characters saved (I know that is the reason it's use is popular) means I have to add 13 for every argument I make optional. This bugs me no end... :P

Comment: @norguard thank you for the answer, its clear now. In my js app the object assigned to the variable is being modified, until the user clicks on "reset", then the variable is assigned to a new object. I wanted to make sure that old object without reference doesn't hang in memory